# Convert formatted lines of delimited text into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode, text-parsing

I have a string of key->value pairs in the following colon-separated format:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "Tim Lincecum"
Reply-To: "Tim Lincecum"
Return-path: "Tim Lincecum"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Subject: Giants Win World Series!
```

How do I get an associative array such that `arr['From'] = "Tim Lincecum",` etc.?

I know there's the `explode()` function, but the only delimiter I see (colon) is in the middle of a key and a value rather than between each pair. How can I approach this?

Comment: Where do you get this from? And why weren't headers separated with newline?

Comment: This is how they are currently stored in our DB.

Comment: are you sure there is no newlines between parameters?

Comment: Does it have newlines between parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I did a good guess in comments - I think i need to repeat it here as an answer:

There is a newlines between parameters, so with

```
$parameters_pairs = explode("\r\n", $parameters_string);
```

you can split it into the name-value pairs, separated with colon.

Answer (score 7):

You could always use regex :)

#### PHP

```
$str = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
'From: "Tim Lincecum"' . "\r\n" . 
'Reply-To: "Tim Lincecum"' . "\r\n" . 
'Return-path: "Tim Lincecum"' . "\r\n" . 
'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" . 
'Subject: Giants Win World Series!';

preg_match_all('/(.*?):\s?(.*?)(\r\n|$)/', $str, $matches);
 
$headers = array_combine(array_map('trim', $matches[1]), $matches[2]);
 
var_dump($headers);
```

#### Output

```
array(6) {
  ["MIME-Version"]=>
  string(3) "1.0"
  ["From"]=>
  string(14) ""Tim Lincecum""
  ["Reply-To"]=>
  string(14) ""Tim Lincecum""
  ["Return-path"]=>
  string(14) ""Tim Lincecum""
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(29) "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
  ["Subject"]=>
  string(24) "Giants Win World Series!"
}
```

[See it on IDEone](http://ideone.com/w2aP8).

Comment: @Jonah Bron I imagine you are referring to just using `\n` as newline delimiter (I forget the spec). I have updated the answer. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @alex: I was referring to to the fact that it wasn't in a key => value form as the OP requested.  But you fixed it.

Comment: @alex: I think you have to use `\z`, not `$` in the regular expression.  I think I tried it once...

Comment: @Jonah Bron Maybe, but it worked in my example. Let me have a Google :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$temp = explode("\r\n", $string);
$sets = array();
foreach ($temp as $value) {
    $array = explode(': ', $value);
    $array[1] = trim($array[1], '"');
    $sets[$array[0]] = $array[1];
}
```

`$string` is the value you're getting from the database.

Comment: I was asking how to do string -> array.

Comment: Oh, you want it the other way around.  Are they delimited by new lines?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding a regular expression approach while parsing a text format that is not handled by a native PHP function/library will require exploding on one delimiter, then looping those results and exploding on another delimiter.

For simplicity and control, just use `preg_match_all()`, then use `array_column()` to form the associative structure from the payload of captured substrings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6jFKJ))

```
preg_match_all(
    '/^([^:]+): (.+)/m',
    $string,
    $m,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
var_export(
    array_column($m, 2, 1)
);
```

The `m` pattern modifier changes the meaning of `^` from "start of the string" to "start of a line".

If you'd like to remove the double quote wrapping that appears on some of the values, here is the pattern adjustment: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/RlWNL)

```
/^([^:]+): ("?)(.+)\2/m
```